# has_many through relationship with an intervening model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-many-through

new to rails and trying to work out the most 'railsy' way to implement the following.

Given below:

```
class Team
  has_many :team_memberships
  has_many :players, through: :team_memberships
end

class TeamMembership
  acts_as_list scope: :team_id
  belongs_to :team
  belongs_to :player
end

class Player
  has_many :team_memberships
  has_many :teams, through: team_memberships
end
```

In my TeamMembership model I have a additional columns `position:integer`, `captain:boolean` and `wicket_keeper:boolean` (Can you tell what I am working on yet.. :))

Given the following:

```
t = Team.first
p = Player.first(11)
t.players << p
```

This populates the TeamMembership model with my player objects nicely.

If I try:

```
t.players[4][:captain] = true
```

it fails with - `ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError: can't write unknown attribute`captain'`

However, I can set it like this:

```
t.team_memberships[4][:captain] = true
```

But this just feels wrong.

Given you should see what I am trying to achieve, is this:

A) The best way to approach this task - if so, is there a way to get at and set the captain attribute directly through the player (if that makes sense)

or

B) Is there a better, more 'railsy' approach that I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you have `t.team_memberships[4][:captain] = true` is correct. I say this because you state in your question that your *TeamMembership* model has `position:integer`, `captain:boolean`, `wicket_keeper:boolean`. So from my understanding you've populated the *TeamMembership* model. However with the following: `t.players[4][:captain] = true` you are trying to access the captain attribute. Which is part of the *TeamMembership* model, and so what I'm trying to say is that your trying to access the attribute *captain* which an attribute of the instance *TeamMembership*. Further to this I believe this error is coming from the `has_many :team_memberships` which you have in your *Player* class, this refers to the associated model. I think its looking for player_id in the *TeamMembership* table. See the following links they may help clarify what you are trying to do:

[API - Ruby on Rails - belongs_to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-belongs_to)

[Guide Ruby on Rails - Belongs_to_association-reference](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#belongs_to-association-reference) have a look at section 4.1.2.6: foreign_key

Comment: Thanks for the answer - however, I am aware why the association through `team_memberships` is working - I was hoping there would be a better way to define the teams<->players relationship...will read through the links, although I have been through them a few times already!!